# JavaScript use map for divide a array of strings base on character like '\n'

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was using a map to trying to clean data send to an API that has sentence parser the problem it really breaks when finding a \n or \t so chose to replace for a time:

```js
const allBulletPoints = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('ul,ol'));
const allBulletPointsText = allBulletPoints.map((element) =>
    element.textContent
        .split(/(\t)|(\n)/g)
        .filter((element) => element && !element.match(/(\t)|(\n)/gi))
);

console.log(allBulletPointsText);
/*
Result:
[   
    [
        "        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit", 
        "        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit", 
        "        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit", 
        "    "
    ],
    [
        "        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit", 
        "        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit", 
        "        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit", 
        "    "
    ]
]

I need to be like this:
[
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit", 
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit", 
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit", 
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit", 
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit", 
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit", 
]
*/
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit</li>
</ul>
<ol>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit</li>
</ol>
```

But right now I want to make to do a little more clean using substr or the split and add all elements seperated then and add to the same array.

Any idea how to get better solution using this functions?

Comment: Click edit, then `[<>]` stack snippet editor and post a [mcve] with relevant HTML plus expected output

Comment: Also `element.textContent.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim()`

Answer (score 0):

Like already mentioned in comments you could trim strings in your first, before doing split.

```
element.innerText
       .trim()
       .split(/(\t)|(\n)/g)
       .filter((element) => element && !element.match(/(\t)|(\n)/gi))
```

Comment: I understand but how concatenate the arrays?

Comment: @RogérioFerreiradeMelo you could iterate again and use Array.prototype.contact 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

or even do something like this

var a = ['hello'];
var b = ['world'];

console.log(a + b); // helloworld

Comment: Okay, I gonna do that

Comment: another great solution published here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15397506/8539736

Answer (score 0):

1. The `element.match(/(\t)|(\n)/gi)` doesn't do anything since [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) already removed all `\t` and `\n`.
2. Instead of [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)ming each line separately, you could build it into the splitting like `split(/\s*?[\t\n]\s*/g)`. Or just use [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) instead to just match what you're interested in.
3. Concatenating the arrays can be done with [`Array#flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

So this might be what you're looking for:

```
const allBulletPointsText = Array.from(
       document.querySelectorAll('ul,ol'),
       e => e.textContent.match(/\S[^\t\n]*\S|\S/g) || []
// or: e => e.textContent.trim().split(/\s*?[\t\n]\s*/g).filter(e => e)
// or: e => e.textContent.split(/^\s+|\s*?[\t\n]\s*|\s+$/g).filter(e => e)
// or: e => e.textContent.split(/[\t\n]+/g).map(e => e.trim()).filter(e => e)
).flat();
```

Comment: Thanks, I never heard about the flat method.